# No sound with bluetooth headphones on Meizu M2

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headphones, meizu

I have a Meizu M2 and Bluetooth headphones. The headphones are paired, and the controls from the headphones work (next, prev, play, pause), but there is no sound. Note that the sound does not come out of the phone's speakers - there is simply none. No, the sound is not set to mute or low. Just so we are clear on that.

Comment: Does the same happen on Bluetooth call also?